# Identical queries; identical indexes; 50000x different speeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table with two foreign key fields: buyer_id and supplier_id.

Schema.rb includes the following fields and indexes:

```
t.bigint "buyer_id"
t.bigint "supplier_id"
t.index ["buyer_id"], name: "index_shipments_on_buyer_id"
t.index ["supplier_id"], name: "index_shipments_on_supplier_id"

# As shown in Postgres itself:
"index_shipments_on_buyer_id" btree (buyer_id)
"index_shipments_on_supplier_id" btree (supplier_id)
```

I am running the same query on both fields:

```
SELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" WHERE "shipments"."buyer_id" = 198917;
SELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" WHERE "shipments"."supplier_id" = 198917;
```

Here's Postgres' approach to each query and the results:

```
db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" WHERE "shipments"."buyer_id" = 198917;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on shipments  (cost=1996.94..228726.45 rows=59403 width=1325) (actual time=143.089..4822.412 rows=38685 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (buyer_id = 198917)
   Heap Blocks: exact=22308
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_shipments_on_buyer_id  (cost=0.00..1982.09 rows=59403 width=0) (actual time=136.081..136.081 rows=38685 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (buyer_id = 198917)
 Planning time: 0.176 ms
 Execution time: 4831.741 ms
(7 rows)

db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "shipments".* FROM "shipments" WHERE "shipments"."supplier_id" = 198917;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_shipments_on_supplier_id on shipments  (cost=0.57..7227.48 rows=1840 width=1325) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (supplier_id = 198917)
 Planning time: 0.203 ms
 Execution time: 0.090 ms
(4 rows)
```

How can I make the first query as fast as the second?

For learning sake, why would Postgres use an entirely different strategy, and achieve  such different results, for what seems like identical scenarios?

Comment: So the one that finds a lot more rows takes a lot longer to do so.  This is not surprising.  Why would you expect them to take the same time?

Comment: is this result disparity repeatable and independent of sequence?

Comment: @jjanes Would you regard it as normal to wait for 4+ seconds for a count on an indexed table? How can we make it fast enough for a production webpage?

Comment: You are not doing a count, you are doing a `select *`.  But yeah, that would be normal if your hardware isn't very good, your data is not well cached, and your table is not well vacuumed.  To get more info on what is going on, you should turn on track_io_tming and then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.